# “Fabric.framework” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer Xcode

Tags: twitter-fabric, xcode10.1, macos-catalina

[image]I just updated to Mac OS Catalina. One of my projects run on Xcode 10.1 and has third party frameworks(Firebase, Fabric) embedded manually.
Now after the update, when. I build the project, I get this error.

“Fabric.framework” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

This leads to build phase failure eventually.

I have already tried the 'Open Anyway' option from Security Preferences but probably because it is a framework, it does not help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just encountered the same error and resolved using below solution.

1. Open "Terminal"
2. Type this command: "**sudo spctl --master-disable**"
3. It will ask for administrator rights, so enter your system password and you're good to go.
4. You will find that under, "**System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Anywhere (this option will appear automatically)**". Which you can change as per your preferences.

Let me know if this helps or not!

Comment: Yes, this helped. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me too. Looks like stack overflow is way faster than Apple Support. I shall post here next time first

Answer (score 5):

While Sohil's solution works, I was able to solve the issue by simply removing the quarantine flag from Fabric.framework:

`xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /path/to/Fabric.framework`

Credit to Zubair for the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644375/8408162).

---

Alternatively (I just discovered this on my own), it looks like you can control this more globally via System Preferences > Privacy > Developer Tools. Checking Terminal allowed building via Fastlane to succeed. I’m not sure if this will also allow Archiving via Xcode to succeed or if you’ll need to add Xcode to the list of allowed apps manually.

[image]