# Can't open app on Simulator MacOS Catalina

Tags: ios-simulator, ios13, macos-catalina

I can't install app on my simulator after update to `MacOS Catalina`, it was fine on earlier versions. But Now when I try to run the app installed in the simulator I get this popup.
[image]

I have changed system Security & Privacy setting using this command in the terminal `sudo spctl --master-disable` and now my it looks like this.
[image]

But even after this I can't run the app, any idea, suggestion ?
My Xcode version is `11.1` & target iOS version is `13.1`, app runs smoothly when ran using xcode, but exported `app` is causing this issue.

Comment: Did you completely turn off code signing in your project? Simulator binaries should be code signed, they're just ad-hoc code signed.

Gatekeeper is usually smart enough to exclude them. Please file a feedback report with the archive produced by `xcrun simctl diagnose` and sudo sysdiagnose -q`

Comment: @russbishop `xcrun diagnose` file https://www.dropbox.com/s/usx167t5ic78ak3/system.log?dl=0 and sudo sysdiagnose file https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzhjklt4avxndq4/system%20by%20sudo.log?dl=0... app id is com.sigmass.gamers

Comment: Those are other log files, I'm not sure from where.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by running the following command.

`xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine <path_to_app>`

It turns out if you download `app` using some browser then it adds a flag which is considered a security threat in `catalina`, running this commands solves the issue.

Comment: It works. It'd be nice to have a more thorough explanation about this. There's this awesome SO post as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198557/understanding-output-of-xattr-p-com-apple-quarantine